# Mapping json to Object

Tags: java

I am trying to map a json response that looks something like this

```
{
  "0" : "name",
  "1" : "school",
  "2" : "hobby",
  "3" : "bank",
  "4" : "games"
}
```

The json response is dyanamic and can include other fields depending on how its called so i cant use something like

```
public class InfoWareAPIResponse {

    private String name; 
    private String school;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

Please how can i create a class that i can map such json object to??

Comment: why can't you set the dynamic fields to null when they are missing?

Comment: Use an unwrapped `Map<String, String>`? Or de-serialize smartly and use a `Map<Integer, String>` maybe.

Comment: I did this    


`public class DataEntry {
        @JsonProperty("entry")

        private Map<String, String> entry;
        
        public DataEntry(){}
    
        public DataEntry(Map<String, String> data){
            this.entry = data;
        }
        
        public void setData(Map<String, String> data) {
            this.entry = data;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getData() {
            return entry;
        } 
    }`

but then i get 

"can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)"

Comment: Use `Jackson` option: ignore unknown fields

Answer (score 0):

you can use a java pojo like this.

```
package com.something;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({})
public class InfoUnAwareAPIResponse {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Valid
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap();

    public InfoUnAwareAPIResponse() {
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (new HashCodeBuilder()).append(this.additionalProperties).toHashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(other instanceof InfoUnAwareAPIResponse)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            InfoUnAwareAPIResponse rhs = (InfoUnAwareAPIResponse) other;
            return (new EqualsBuilder()).append(this.additionalProperties, rhs.additionalProperties).isEquals();
        }
    }
}
```

And marshel string like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    InfoUnAwareAPIResponse in = mapJsonToObject("{\"hello\":\"world\"}", InfoUnAwareAPIResponse.class);
    System.out.print("" + in.toString());
}

public static <T> T mapJsonToObject(String input, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    T requestedClass = objectMapper.readValue(input, clazz);
    return requestedClass;
}
```

I ran the above code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @olatunji did you try this?

Comment: Would try this now and let you know what happens. Thanks. Cheers

Comment: I get "No suitable constructor found for" whenever i try to deserialize

Comment: updated my answer, the above solution works for me, can you please check?